# C# Copy file with specify date and time range

Tags: c#, datetime, directory-structure

In Visual C#:

I wish to copy a list of file(s) of specify range of date and time from 1 folder to another. I keep getting all files instead of just the file I want.

E.g:

20th Feb 2019 2am to 2nd March 2019 1am (Base on Date time modified)

Copy

```
D:\Data\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\\*.log
```

to

```
E:\MyLogs\D\Data\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\
```

What function or library should I be looking at?

Comment: Are you looking for files which got added in that specific range and move them to other folder?

Comment: Yes, sorry miss type the title, corrected it

Comment: Can you post what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try code like below

Import `System.IO` to use `DirectoryInfo` from it.

I am also importing `System.Linq` to use `Where` method from it.

Say you have your directorypath in a variable say `yourDirectoryPath`

```
// Specify the directory you want to use
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(yourDirectoryPath);
// Check if your directory exists and only then proceed further
if (directory.Exists){
    //You would be having your fromdate and toDate in two variables like fromDate, toDate
    // files variable below will have all the files that has been lastWritten between the given range
    var files = directory.GetFiles()
                 .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= toDate);
 }
```

Now you can use your existing code (let me know in case you didnt) to copy all the files from the folder to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to filter the files which was modified/created during the specified period.  You can do so as following.

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
var listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod = directory.GetFiles("SubFolder3*.log")
                    .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= endDate);
```

Then, you could iterate over the result to copy them to destination folder.

```
  foreach(var file in listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod)
  {
    File.Copy(file.FullName,Path.Combine(destinationFolder,file.Name));
  }
```

Please note to make the code complete you need to add checks to ensure Source and Destination Folders exists. I leave that for you to complete.